# Subject verb agreement have/has

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

> Does your cat have/has any distinguishing marks?

Here, if the subject is 'cat' then the verb 'has' is ok.
But it seems that 'marks' is the subject here.What could be the right answer.

Comment: Cat is the subject, but the verb is "does have"  So "Has" is wrong. ]There is a duplicate question here.

Comment: The subject is "your cat". The auxiliary verb "does" requires a plain (infinitive) verb as complement, so "have" is correct.